# Destiny storage solution

Tags: xbox-360, ps3, destiny, xbox-network

Activision are offering a storage solution to those affected by TTK(The Taken King) update, for those with only 20GB storage. What is this solution?

Comment: So I ordered this solution and it has arrived...

Answer (score 1):

The Activision Destiny storage solution is a PNY(Company name) 32GB USB 3.0 stick that is preformatted for Xbox 360 out of the package.  The solution itself is for everybody and is to use a USB to install the remaining updates as after compatibility pack 5 is installed, all other compatibility packs are able to be installed to the USB, including Destiny digital edition, which previously had to be ran off the HDD.

Answer (score -3):

With this "storage solution", Bungie and Activision are give PS3 and XB360 users a bigger hard drive for The Taken King, but this isn't going to matter when Destiny isn't supported on last gen around Year 3.

I hope this helped.

Comment: No last gen year 3? Thank you.

Comment: @Brok3n Yeah it's sad to see destiny go this quickly on the last gen, but Bungie have to move forward and if they have the last gen consoles, they can't make Destiny what they want it to be.

Comment: While I agree that it's *likely* next gen consoles will be dropped from future releases, I haven't seen any official announcements from Bungie to that effect. Do you have any sources for your assertion?

Comment: Not yet, I have heard from a couple of people saying The same thing, but I will look for any announcements from Bungie

Comment: If this is pure speculation or rumour, it should not be posted as an answer.